# Constraining Generic Function Parameter

Tags: f#

I have this code

```
let inline ProcessExpendableADGroups (input : ('a * SPUser) seq) =
  input
  |> Seq.filter (fun (_, u : SPUser) -> u.IsDomainGroup = true)       
  |> Seq.filter (fun (_, u : SPUser) -> ADUtility.IsADGroupExpandable u.LoginName = true)      
  |> List.ofSeq
  |> List.iter( 
      fun ( li : 'a, u : SPUser) -> 
        let userList = ADUtility.GetUsers u.LoginName 
        if (Seq.length userList <= 500) then
          userList
          |> Seq.filter (fun l -> InfobarrierPolicy.IsUserInPolicy l "FW" = true) 
          |> Seq.iter (
              fun ln ->
                let x = ADUtility.GetNameAndEmail ln 
                let (email, name) = x.Value
                SPUtility.CopyRoleAssignment li u.LoginName ln email name
                li.Update()
              )
          SPUtility.RemoveRoleAssignment li u
      )      

list3 
|> List.iter (
    fun w -> 
      SPUtility.GetDirectAssignmentsforListItems w |> ProcessExpendableADGroups
      SPUtility.GetDirectAssignmentsforFolders w |> ProcessExpendableADGroups
      SPUtility.GetDirectAssignmentsforLists w |> ProcessExpendableADGroups
      SPUtility.GetDirectAssignmentsforWeb w |> ProcessExpendableADGroups
   )
```

Here the methods GetDirectAssignmentsforListItems returns a Sequence of tuples (SPListItem * SPUser)
GetDirectAssignmentsforWeb returns a sequence of tuples (SPWeb * SPUser).

I need to send this sequence to a function which does very similar processing on these items except that in the end I have to call a method called "Update" on these items.

I have written a method with Generic parameter but I am having a problem when I call Update on the generic parameter.

I am not able to constrain this parameter to say that the parameter must have a method called Update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use member constraints and [statically resolved type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx) to do so.

```
let inline ProcessExpendableADGroups (input : (^a * SPUser) seq) = //'
  input
  |> Seq.filter (fun (_, u) -> u.IsDomainGroup && ADUtility.IsADGroupExpandable u.LoginName)       
  |> Seq.iter( 
      fun (li, u) -> 
        let userList = ADUtility.GetUsers u.LoginName 
        if (Seq.length userList <= 500) then
          userList
          |> Seq.filter (fun l -> InfobarrierPolicy.IsUserInPolicy l "FW") 
          |> Seq.iter (
              fun ln ->
                let x = ADUtility.GetNameAndEmail ln 
                let (email, name) = x.Value
                SPUtility.CopyRoleAssignment li u.LoginName ln email name
                (^a : (member Update : unit -> unit) li) //'
              )
          SPUtility.RemoveRoleAssignment li u
      )
```

There is also a series of helpful articles on the topic [here](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2009/09/28/generically-constraining-f-part-ii/).

A few improvements I have done on the function above:

- A series of `Seq.filter` could be collapsed to one `Seq.filter` , and `= true` is always a code smell.
- `List.ofSeq` and `List.iter` could be replaced by `Seq.iter`. When you use `Seq.iter`, a lazy sequence will be evaluated anyway.
- Do not write redundant type annotations such as `li: 'a` and `u: SPUser`. Since you use piping and have type annotation for `input`, the type checker would be able to infer correct types.

Comment: Why do we declare the member Update : unit -> unit twice? once in the function header and then again at the time  of calling?

Comment: I was overcareful. I updated the answer to remove that and add a link explaining differences between `'a` and `^a`.

Answer (score 2):

The constraint just looks like this (it doesn't need to be at the method decleration - just where you use it)

```
 (^a: ( member Update: unit-> unit )t))
```

This will call a method called `Update` on the object `t`

Comment: little confused. the generic parameter should be 'a or ^a?

Comment: For this type of inline constraints you need to use `^a`.  Normally though you need `'a`